# How can I run a Python for loop for each row in a spreadsheet?

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | List |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rc20, fc20 |
| 2 | rc19, rc20, fc20 |
| 3 | cc20, rc20, fc19, fc20 |

Note the multiple values in each cell of the List column. I need to append each row with duplicate values with 21 at the end. So the first row would be

### |List|

|rc20, fc20, rc21, fc21|.

I can do that on a single row with a Python loop like this:

```
list = ['rc20', 'fc20']
for i in list:
    if i[-2:] == '20':
        list.append(i[0:-2] + '21')
```

However, what I can't figure out is how to run code like this over each row in the spreadsheet. I think maybe pandas could work here, but I am stuck.

Comment: What is that list? Are you opening a csv file? Are you creating a list? How do you have named columns in your list?

Comment: I'm opening a CSV file. I want to store each row in the list column as a python list so I can run the loop to add new values. Unless there's an easier way to add the new values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

rows=[["rc20","fc20"],
            ["rc19", "rc20", "fc20"], 
            ["cc20","rc20", "fc19"]]

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    new_row = row.copy()
    for v in row:
        if v[-2:] == "20":
            new_row.append(v[:-2]+"21")
    rows[i] = new_row
print(rows)
```